# How can I make a webpage expire after a certain date and become not accessible?

Tags: html, apache, web, server

Is there a way in Apache to make URLs only accessible during certain times/inaccessible after a specific point in time? I am looking for a solution using Apache only; I know it can be done manually or by scheduling a cron job to remove the file.

#### Example:

I have a web page accessible via http://example.com/aboutthisproject.html which I want to send to clients via email. I want that link to expire and the page not to be accessible after, let's say, one week. So when someone who has the link types in their browser http://example.com/aboutthisproject.html they should get a 404 error.

What options do I have besides manually moving or renaming the file? I want to be able to set an expiring date for that page and forget about having to keep in mind to go back and rename or move the file.

Comment: You could use PHP at the top of the file to compare the current date to a specified expiration date and `exit` if you've passed it.

Comment: @deceze Please be more specific I don't understand what is not clear

Comment: Create a cron job to delete or rename the page

Comment: It’s not unclear, it’s *too broad*. There’s an infinite number of things you could do. Tell us a bit about what possibilities you have technologically and skill-wise.

Comment: I gave you the OS and the webserver software.... what else do you need? As I said this should be handled by Apache if possible. (server side) not by OS (scripting/cron) or a web programming language like PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look into apache mod_rewrite with server variables date+time? Using Rewrite condition based on date+time you could do a 404.

see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

example:

```
RewriteEngine On
# between 03 am and 4am
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >02
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <05

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /morning/index.html
```

Comment: thank you! see it was not difficult or vague for someone who understood the question but @deceze rushed to put it on hold....